# How to correct the style height of a paypal button and take out the top and bottom border lines in the HTML element

Tags: html, paypal

Usually a standard default paypal button has a height smaller image that the aesthetic element causing a horrible cut under the button. Not leaving enough space to cards and cutting down the last part of the image. Sometimes you can see two lines at top edge and bottom edge.

How can be corrected this height and border inside the html given by paypal without using css?

```html
<form action="" method="post" target="_top">
  
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value=""/>
      <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online."/>

</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried to create your image?

Comment: No want to use the standard button given !

Comment: use standard image, but remove things that you don't need.

Comment: I know how to create a new image. But I would solve this common paypal style problem first.

Comment: do you know that you can't change image through HTML

Comment: I do no want to change the image through html. I want to change the height of the element. If i use css adding padding and border, the image is no more cut down. But there is same case where we do not have access to the css. So probably there is a way to include the style in the html. pushing the height bigger just to revile the entire paypal image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79697/discussion-between-soaringline-and-senad-meskin).

Comment: Probably in one tag is necessary to add style="property:value" or more than one property combination.